# How to block browsers to store api data in cache?

Tags: spring-boot, firefox, browser-cache

I am currently developing an application using spring boot framework. while testing firefox browser stores api response in disk space, how can i block browser or take an action for not to store api data in disk space.

I have tried sending cachebuster with api and also used cachecontrol but nothing worked.
also i tried no-cache, no-store but still no positive response.